# Retrieve correct application label from installed apps

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I know that there are several questions about *how to get the label
of an application*. But I could not find an appropriate answer to my question:

What is the difference in using `ApplicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)` to

```
getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(appinfo).toString();
```

What should I use?

Is there a difference in the returned string, based on localization?

Why does loadLabel sometimes returns an empty string?

**Background:**

For my app I want to display a **list of all applications installed** on the users
device. Currently I am using `ApplicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)` to get the name of every application, but sometimes it seems to return an empty string.
I just need the **name of the application**, **as** it is displayed **in** the **home launcher** of the device.

I appreciate any help to understand the difference and handle localization
problems.

Comment: "as it is displayed in the home launcher of the device" -- that is not the name of the application. The home screen launcher shows *activities*, not applications. An application can have zero, one, or several activities with the `MAIN`/`LAUNCHER` `<intent-filter>`. And the labels for those activities do not have to bear any resemblance to the name of the application, if the developer does not want them to.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! You are totally right, on the home screen are activities and they can have their own label. But if I now want to display a list of the apps. And if I understand you right, ApplicationInfo.loadLabel can return an empty string. So, do I need to query the applicable launcher activities too, to get a label, if the app-label is not defined?

Comment: "So, do I need to query the applicable launcher activities too, to get a label, if the app-label is not defined?" -- I don't really know how that would work reliably. If there are three launcher activities, which one's label would you choose? If you are sure that you want application labels, and not launcher activity labels, you might poke around the code for the Settings app and see what they use when generating the list of installed apps.

Comment: I've seen apps in the settings that were titled with their packageName. I assume that is the "last resort" if neither label nor name are defined in manifest. That would be ok, if I there is no other reliable source of an apps label/name. But do you now if the getApplicationLabel method has any advantage over loadLoabel?

Comment: I do not recall ever using either method for applications. I have worked with getting labels for activities, and there I never had a problem with `loadLabel()`.